# why does colon ":" in Uri passed to Uri.MakeRelativeUri cause an exception?

Tags: c#, uri

The following line of code gives an exception.  Is this a bug in the framework?  If not what approach could I take instead?

It seems to be the ":" (colon) that causes in the issue, however I do see such a URI working on production websites ok (i.e. seems to be a valid URI in the real world)

```
Uri relativeUri = new Uri("http://test.com/asdf").MakeRelativeUri(new Uri("http://test.com/xx:yy"));
// gives => System.UriFormatException: A relative URI cannot be created because the 
// 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI

Uri relativeUri = new Uri("http://test.com/asdf").MakeRelativeUri(new Uri("http://test.com/xxyy"));
// this works - removed the colon between the xx and yy
```

PS.  Specifically can I ask given the above is the case, what .NET class/method could I use (noting I am parsing a HTML page from the web) to take (a) the page URI and (b) the relative string from a HTML HREF argument [e.g. would have been "/xx:yy" in this case] and return the valid URI that could be used to address that resource?

In other words how do I mimic the behavior of a browser that translates the HREF and the page URI to produce the URI it uses to go to that resource when you click on it.

Comment: Jon Postel: "be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send".  Please quote the RFC and its paragraph number that proofs that this is a valid URI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consider it a bug.

RFC1738 says that `:` (amongst other characters) *may* be reserved for special meaning within a scheme. However the `http` scheme does not reserve it in the path part

```
Within the <path> and <searchpart> components, "/", ";", "?" are reserved.
```

(Not `:`.)

```
hsegment       = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
```

So, `http://test.com/xx:yy` is a valid URI. The newer RFC3968 agrees:

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

However of course, relativised against `http://test.com/asdf`, the resultant `xx:yy` would be an absolute URI and not a valid relative URI:

```
path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
                ; non-zero-length segment without any colon ":"
```

So `MakeRelativeUri` is kind of right to report there's a problem, but really it *should* be fixing it automatically by encoding the `:` that is valid in an absolute URI to a `%3A` that is valid in the first segment of a relative URI.

I would generally try to avoid `MakeRelativeUri` in favour of root-relative URIs, which are easier to extract and don't have this problem (`/xx:yy` is OK).

Comment: thank bobince thats great - do you know of a direct .net method that gives the root-relative URI from a PageURI + HRefString?  Just looking for one at the moment...or do you have to "do it yourself"?

Comment: actually I should probably start a new question for this and mark this one as finished...I'll do this

Comment: created this specific question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144150/c-question-how-do-i-convert-a-pageuri-href-to-an-absolute-url-uri

Comment: really great answer - especially the solid references.

Answer (score 1):

Colons play a special role in URLs - to denote a port for instance and are therefor 'reserved' ([see here](http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)).

> URLs use some characters for special
>   use in defining their syntax. When
>   these characters are not used in their
>   special role inside a URL, they need
>   to be encoded

So, the colon should be escaped.

Comment: thanks Shane - I've made the question more specific re what would help me out

Answer (score 0):

If a colon is found it tries to parse the value that follows the colon as a port number and it will fail if you don't provide a valid port number. See [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread215664.html) for an example of a similar issue and [MSDN link for UriFormatException details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriformatexception.aspx).

Comment: thanks Tanner - I've made the question more specific re what would help me out