# C# question - how do I convert a PageURI & Href to an absolute URL/URI?

Tags: c#, .net, url, uri, href

How do I convert a PageURI & Href to an absolute URL/URI in C#?

i.e. I am scanning a web page at a given PageURI and in the HTML have link/node with a HREF, and want to translate this HREF into a valid absolute URI.

Background - note the trouble I was having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143856/why-does-colon-in-uri-passed-to-uri-makerelativeuri-cause-an-exception)

Comment: So you're looking for the standard way of getting an absolute URL in C# without using System.Uri?

Comment: oh...I see my mixup...shouldn't have really had to ask about this :(

Answer (score 2):

new URI(uri, string) does it